# C++ initialization: no brackets vs empty brackets

Tags: c++, initialization, default-constructor

What's the difference between `Foo foo;` and `Foo foo{};`? (and why user-defined ctor matters, as shown below)

I wrote some test code and found that when no user-defiened ctor is provided, `Foo foo;` gives an uninitialized `Foo` whereas `Foo foo{};` performs zero-initialization, but both gives uninitialized objects when a user-defined ctor is provided.

```c++
#include <iostream>

constexpr std::size_t LEN = 10;

struct Foo
{
    Foo() {}  // user-defined ctor, though empty
    int a[LEN];
};

struct Bar
{
    // no user-defined ctor
    int a[LEN];
};

template <typename FooBar>
void print(const FooBar &foobar)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < LEN; ++i) {
        std::cout << foobar.a[i] << ", ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    Foo foo1;
    print(foo1);
    Foo foo2{};
    print(foo2);
    Bar bar1;
    print(bar1);
    Bar bar2{};
    print(bar2);
    return 0;
}
```

A possible output(g++10.3, MSYS2, Win10):

```
-1369499968, 490, -1788275447, 32759, 1, 0, 2, 0, -1369500000, 490,
1, 0, 0, 0, -1788275056, 32759, 24, 0, 0, 0,
-1788275408, 32759, 8, 0, 0, 0, 268501009, 0, -1369503896, 490,
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
```

Comment: There is no difference between `Foo foo;` and `Foo foo{};`, both just initialize with _user-defined_ default constructor. With `Bar`, the situation is different and `Bar bar{};` is _aggregate-initizliaed_, which, in your case, _zero-initialize_ all array elements.

Comment: @Daniel Langr So why a user-defined empty default ctor is not equivalent to a compiler-provided default ctor?

Comment: Because this is the way how C++ works. Some relevant parts from the documentation: _"if T is a class type with at least one user-provided constructor of any kind, the default constructor is called"_ and _"In all cases, if the empty pair of braces {} is used and T is an aggregate type, aggregate-initialization is performed instead of value-initialization"_ (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization). Though being complicated, these rules allow, for instance, implementing `std::array`, which is an aggregate type without user-provided constructors.

Comment: @Daniel Langr Never though it could be so complicated... I think I'd better resort to more robust coding styles that depends as less as possible on those tons of detailed inialization rules

Comment: Totally agree with that. Types like `std::array` are kind-of specific corner cases. Typically, when you design some class that represents objects with some "content", you likely want to user-provide all _special member functions_.